# How to use django-tls in Django unit tests

Tags: django, python-3.x, werkzeug, django-unittest

I'm trying to write some unit tests on a `Django` (I'm using `Django==1.9.12`) application that uses `django-tls`, but I always get this exception: `RuntimeError: no object bound to request`. My code looks like this:

`settings.py`:

As in [django-tls doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tls/0.0.2) I added the line `'tls.TLSRequestMiddleware'` to my `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'tls.TLSRequestMiddleware',
]
```

I wrote a method to test it on a module called `utils.py`:

```
from tls import request


def print_tls_found_by_django_tls():
    """
    Just print the request instance found by django-tls.

    :return: 
    """
    print(request)
```

On my `test_utils.py` I have tried to follow the [Werkzeug test utilities](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/test/) because `Werkzeug` is what `django-tls` uses to discover the `request` instance. So I coded something like this for testing that:

```
from werkzeug.test import EnvironBuilder

from django.test import TestCase

from example_app.utils import print_tls_found_by_django_tls


class TestUtils(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.build_tls_request()

    def test_print_tls_found_by_django_tls(self):
        print_tls_found_by_django_tls()

    def build_tls_request(self):

        return EnvironBuilder(method='GET').get_request()
```

but then the exception is there:

```
(venv) vladir@vladir:~/work/project_example_all/example/example_app$ coverage run ./manage.py test example_app.tests.TestUtils.test_print_tls_found_by_django_tls
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_print_tls_found_by_django_tls (affiliate_tracking.tests.test_utils.TestUtils)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vladir/work/project_example_all/example/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 70, in __getattr__
    return self.__storage__[self.__ident_func__()][name]
KeyError: 140239354230528

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vladir/work/project_example_all/example/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 308, in _get_current_object
    return getattr(self.__local, self.__name__)
  File "/home/vladir/work/project_example_all/example/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 72, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: request

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vladir/work/project_example_all/example/example_app/affiliate_tracking/tests/test_utils.py", line 15, in test_print_tls_found_by_django_tls
    print_tls_found_by_django_tls()
  File "/home/vladir/work/project_example_all/example/example_app/affiliate_tracking/utils.py", line 67, in print_tls_found_by_django_tls
    print(request)
  File "/home/vladir/work/project_example_all/example/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 366, in <lambda>
    __str__ = lambda x: str(x._get_current_object())
  File "/home/vladir/work/project_example_all/example/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 310, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError('no object bound to %s' % self.__name__)
RuntimeError: no object bound to request

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I would appreciate any help or clue you could give me to find a solution to this. I have tried several things but without any luck. Thanks in advance mates.